# Is there a way to create an IDbContext interface for DI (using AutoFac)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to create an IDbContext interface for DI (using AutoFac)?
i am using asp.net mvc 5 & EF 6.
and i would like to create an Interface for Dependency Injection.
There is some way to do it?

Currently i am register my Context class and it will work fine

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomContext>().SingleInstance().InstancePerLifeTimeScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

DbContext's should be short-lived. A common pattern for working with EF Contexts is the Unit of Work pattern. There are a few out there for EF that can help manage the scope of a DbContext. At worst for ASP.Net you would want the DbContext lifetime set to the Request, no longer.

Option 1: (Recommended) Register a unit of work implementation (Such as Medhime's DbContextScope) and let that manage the DbContext scope. These follow the Interface/Concrete definitions to work well with DI.

Option 2: Register a DbContextFactory and use that to provide DbContexts.  I.e.

```
using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
{
   // ....
}
```

Where `ContextFactory` is a defined `DbContextFactory` class implementing an `IDbContextFactory` interface.

Option 3: Register the DbContext itself as a PerRequest lifetime scope.

If your goal is to inject DbContexts to facilitate testing, I would highly recommend adopting a Repository pattern (Not a Generic Repository pattern I.e. `Repository<TEntity>`) and utilizing either Option 1 or Option 2. The advantage of a repository is that it serves as a boundary for the unit tests. Your "code under test" can then be served a Mocked repository class which in turn returns stubbed entities or `IEnumerable<TEntity>`/`IQueryable<TEntity>`.  Mocking DbContexts and their DbSets is honestly a PITA.  Repository methods can be tested if & as desired using integration-style tests talking to a real database.